# Tenor Gifs not loading in Discord.Js embeds

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to create a system where a alert command is used and a message along with a random gif is send as an embed. This is working for gifs in the format https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/ but not in the format https://tenor.com/view/. The tenor ones just load and load and then show the little discord poop symbol (failed to load).

Is there a way to make the tenor gifs work or will I have to download and make them all discord attachments

```js
const wallpapers = [
   'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/876621706549149736/942638416821104650/boss_badass.gif',
    'https://tenor.com/view/clone-commando-shadow-of-the-republic-gif-20193389'
  ];

  const response = wallpapers[Math.floor(Math.random() * wallpapers.length)];
  
  const alert = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Base Event Alert")
    .setDescription("Filler Text")
      .setImage(response)
    .setColor("#1773BA");
  
  message.channel.send(alert);
```

Comment: You'll have to get the direct gif url, it should end in ".gif"

Comment: Ah nice, that fixed it thanks

Comment: I used @Elitezen comment and made it into an answer. If it helped, please mark it as the best answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Elitezen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12464931/elitezen) said, you must have the URL's ending, `.gif`, for discord to recognize and display it. So, for example, [`https://tenor.com/view/clone-commando-shadow-of-the-republic-gif-20193389`](https://tenor.com/view/clone-commando-shadow-of-the-republic-gif-20193389) would become [`https://tenor.com/view/clone-commando-shadow-of-the-republic-gif-20193389.gif`](https://tenor.com/view/clone-commando-shadow-of-the-republic-gif-20193389.gif).


Your code would look like this:

```js
const wallpapers = [
    'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/876621706549149736/942638416821104650/boss_badass.gif',
    'https://tenor.com/view/clone-commando-shadow-of-the-republic-gif-20193389.gif'
];

const response = wallpapers[Math.floor(Math.random() * wallpapers.length)];

const alert = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Base Event Alert')
    .setDescription('Filler Text')
    .setImage(response)
    .setColor("#1773BA");

message.channel.send(alert);
```

**Hoped this helped!**